# SQL Server rows count return with inner join more than once in same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have this code

```
select 
    count(cat_item_tb.item_id),
    count(t.item_id) 
from 
    cat_tb 
inner join
    item_tb on cat_tb.cat_id = item_tb.cat_id
inner join
    cat_item_tb on item_tb.item_id = cat_item_tb.item_id and t.ss = 0
inner join
    cat_item_tb t on item_tb.item_id = t.item_id and t.ss = 1
```

All I need to return value without duplicate. In past code it must return 7 in every count but it's return 49  the two `count()` affected each other. I use distinct but it does not return the correct count, because there is (item_id) more than once in table

Thank you so much

Comment: Sample and desired results would really help.

Comment: This is expected when there is more than one row with the same value on both sides of the join. So it's your data rather than the query.

Comment: Mind that 7 * 7 = 49   ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the task, you could use groub by to get desired results

```
select count(cat_item_tb.item_id), cat_item_tb.ss
from cat_tb 
inner join item_tb on cat_tb.cat_id = item_tb.cat_id
inner join cat_item_tb on item_tb.item_id = cat_item_tb.item_id 
where t.ss = 0 or t.ss = 1
group by cat_item_tb.ss
```

The query will return 2 rows with count values in first column.

More info about group by is here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you need to count distinct, to count the unique values

```
... 
count(DISTINCT cat_item_tb.item_id) 
...
```

The 2 counts in your query will be the same. That's simply because you INNER JOIN on those item_id's. So they will be identical by defenition.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanted to write something like:

```
select 
    count(c1.item_id),
    count(c2.item_id) 
from 
    cat_tb                  as a
    inner join item_tb      as b    on ( a.cat_id = b.cat_id )
    inner join cat_item_tb  as c1   on ( b.item_id = c1.item_id ) and ( c1.ss = 0 )
    inner join cat_item_tb  as c2   on ( b.item_id = c2.item_id ) and ( c2.ss = 1 )
```

This won't work because of the inner joins. If the first join of c1 returns 3 rows and the second join of c2 returns 4 rows, you end up with count = 3*4

Try this:

```
;with cte1 as (
    select
        b.item_id, 
        'c1_count' = count( c1.item_id ) 
    from
        item_tb                 as b
        left join cat_item_tb  as c1   on ( b.item_id = c1.item_id ) and ( c1.ss = 0 )        
    group by
        b.item_id
),
cte2 as (
    select 
        b.item_id,
        'c2_count' = count(c2.item_id) 
    from 
        item_tb                 as b        
        left join cat_item_tb  as c2   on ( b.item_id = c2.item_id ) and ( c2.ss = 1 )
    group by
        b.item_id
)
select
    a.item_id, a.c1_count, b.c2_count
from
    cte1            as a
    inner join cte2 as b on ( b.item_id = a.item_id )
```

For performance reasons you could replace the `left join` in ctes with `inner join` **ONLY** if you are sure that **there are** rows in  `cat_item_tb` with item_id and **all of them** has the `ss` column set to 0 or 1.